# Python - tkinter interface, using bind works only the first time (when running the program)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, bind

I'm attaching the code below.
There is an event on "focus out", the event triggers once when the code is initialized. Afterwards focusing out of the Spinbox does not trigger the event anymore. The question is, why? And, how do I fix that?

code :

```
import tkinter as tk
import os, time

def spinBoxValidateRange(widget_name):
    print(str(widget_name.winfo_name()) + " focus out")
   

# Making a window, and giving it some settings
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.winfo_toplevel().title("Test")
# creating a user GUI
default_pady = 2
default_padx = 5

sbx_max_img_width = tk.Spinbox(from_=500, to=5000, width = 4)
sbx_max_img_width.delete(0, 'end')
sbx_max_img_width.insert(0, 1000)
sbx_max_img_height = tk.Spinbox(from_=500, to=5000, width = 4)
sbx_max_img_height.delete(0, 'end')
sbx_max_img_height.insert(0, 1000)
sbx_max_img_width.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "W", pady = default_pady, padx = default_padx)
sbx_max_img_height.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = "W", pady = default_pady, padx = default_padx)
sbx_max_img_width.bind("<FocusOut>", spinBoxValidateRange(sbx_max_img_width))
sbx_max_img_height.bind("<FocusOut>", spinBoxValidateRange(sbx_max_img_height))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's the same reason as this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: Thank you. This was enough to correct my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected code (that works) -

```
import tkinter as tk
import os, time

def spinBoxValidateRange(some_widget):
    print(str(some_widget.widget.winfo_name()) + " focus out")
   

# Making a window, and giving it some settings
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.winfo_toplevel().title("Test")
# creating a user GUI
default_pady = 2
default_padx = 5

sbx_max_img_width = tk.Spinbox(from_=500, to=5000, width = 4)
sbx_max_img_width.delete(0, 'end')
sbx_max_img_width.insert(0, 1000)
sbx_max_img_height = tk.Spinbox(from_=500, to=5000, width = 4)
sbx_max_img_height.delete(0, 'end')
sbx_max_img_height.insert(0, 1000)
sbx_max_img_width.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "W", pady = default_pady, padx = default_padx)
sbx_max_img_height.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = "W", pady = default_pady, padx = default_padx)
sbx_max_img_width.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda parameter = sbx_max_img_width: spinBoxValidateRange(parameter))
sbx_max_img_height.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda parameter = sbx_max_img_height: spinBoxValidateRange(parameter))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the lambdas, just `sbx_max_img_width.bind("<FocusOut>", spinBoxValidateRange)` and `sbx_max_img_height.bind("<FocusOut>", spinBoxValidateRange)`.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, I need the parameter. It is not obvious from the code, but I am using the name of the widget in order to identify which spinbox is it and use it's min and max values to verify that the value is within bounds.

Comment: Did you try it?  Callback of `bind()` expects a argument which is the `Event` object and so `some_widget` in your definition of `def spinBoxValidateRange(some_widget)` will be actually the `Event` object.

Comment: Did I try the code I've posted as the answer? Yes, it works for my purpose.

Comment: No did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, not yet, but honestly I am happy with my results and I plan to stick with that solution for now.